# How to replace something in a file

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a config file with some information, in the following format:

```
define("FTP_USERNAME","583hdsljf");
define("FTP_PASSWORD","******");
define("FTP_FOLDER1","greatfolder");
define("FTP_FOLDER2","greatfolder");
```

Normally I use str_replace() when replacing values in a template, but I need to know what to replace when I do that (ex. [REPLACE_THIS_WITH_FTP_USERNAME]). I can't do that in this case, since all the values above is unknown and different when I want to replace with a new values.

Any suggestions?

Note: Some of the values in the config file might be the same.

Comment: I would suggest storing the data in a more easily manipulated format, such as JSON.  That way you can easily edit them both by hand and programmatically.  What you're trying to do now is going to require a bit of hacky regex (or a PHP parser...).  (You could also store it in plain PHP variables like $config = `array('username' => 'blah')` but depending on your requirements JSON might actually end up being easier.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$content = preg_replace('/(define\("FTP_USERNAME",")[^"]+("\);)
/', '$1new username$2', $content);
```

However, I'd strongly recommend you to use a standardized format such as JSON for your config file. While the regex above does work it will break as soon as someone edits the file manually and uses e.g. single quotes instead of double quotes. It would also break with a string containing escaped quotes.

Comment: Have been looking a bit into JSON, but it seems the problem will be the same? $config='{
 "FTP_USERNAME":"583hdsljf",
 "FTP_PASSWORD":"*****",
 "FTP_FOLDER1":"greatfolder",
 "FTP_FOLDER2":"greatfolder"
}';

Comment: Well your `$config` should be the object returned by `json_decode()`. Then you simply do `$config->FTP_USERNAME = 'whatever';` and write `json_encode($config)` to your file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_replace as below...

```
$str='
define("FTP_USERNAME","583hdsljf");
define("FTP_PASSWORD","******");
';
$strval='NEW VALUE';
$str=preg_replace('/FTP_USERNAME","(.*)"/','FTP_USERNAME","'.$strval.'"',$str);
echo $str;
```

Answer (score -2):

I would've parsed the file and matched each line against a regexp.

For instance,

```
$line = 'define("hello", "hi")';
preg_match('/define\(\s*[\'"](.*)[\'"]\s*,\s*[\'"](.*)[\'"]\s*\)/', $line, $matches);
```

should give us a set of

```
Array
(
    [0] => define("hello", "hi")
    [1] => hello
    [2] => hi
)
```

Then we just match our key against $matches[1] and exchange the line (or expression) for a new one!